# Angle of repose for cylinders and spheres

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, terminology

Is angle of repose of a cylinder or a sphere same as [angle of repose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_repose) of a block on an rough incline? How to calculate it for spheres and cylinders?

Comment: -1 It is not clear what you are asking about. You ought to have identified the context in which you have seen this phrase.

Answer (score 1):

From the linked Wikipedia page:

> The term has a related usage in mechanics, where it refers to the maximum angle at which an object can rest on an inclined plane without sliding down. This angle is equal to the arctangent of the coefficient of static friction *μs* between the surfaces.

Given that you are asking about solid objects rather than granular media, I assume this is the definition of angle of repose which you mean to use.

Note that the calculation requires only the coefficient of stiction, not the area of the contact patch. So using objects of the same material, there should be no difference between a block, cylinder or sphere on the ramp; they each have the same coefficient of friction, so they will each have the same angle of repose.

Of course, once you stray from polygonal to curved shapes, the hard part isn't keeping the object from sliding... It's keeping it from rocking or rolling. An elliptical lens can, in a rocking motion, 'scoot' itself down the ramp if the perpendicular momentum at the low end of rocking overcomes static friction. Cylinders and spheres are completely hopeless. I recommend restricting experimental test objects to relatively flat-sided shapes.

Comment: Since cylinders and spheres will roll down an inclined plane for any angle of inclination, I think this cannot be what the question is askingabout.